# Objective-c [iOS разработка] работа с таблицами

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, xcode, ios7

Доброе время суток всем пользователям данного сайта!

У меня возникла проблема при разработке под iOS одной программы, в общем у меня есть два ViewController'a, на одном из них у меня таблица с записями, а на другом детальное отображение записей, собственно переход по ячейке приводит к подробной записи с рисунком и т.д.

Собственно суть проблемы. Мне нужно сделать так как в приложении Notes на iPhon'e/iPod'e. Что бы я с детального контроллера мог переключать записи по кнопке, как это можно реализовать?

Буду очень благодарен вам за помощь!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно попробовать следующим образом

1. `UITableViewController` со списком свех заметок
2. **Subclass of UIPageViewController** (MYNotesPageController) с кастомным методом `- (id)initWithNotes:(NSArray *)items initialIndex:(NSInteger)index` (либо заправшиваем все объекты MYNote из CoreData через NSFetchedResultsController или как-то еще)
3. `MYNoteDetailsVC` с методом `- (id)initWithNote:(MYNote *)note` - контроллер отображение каждой конкретной note
4. Добавляем логику в UIPageController для смены страниц - объектов MYNoteDetailsVC
5. в контроллере со списком заметок

   `- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
        {
       MYNotesPageController *pageVC = [[MYNotesPageController alloc] initWithNotes:self.items initialIndex:indexPath.row];
       [self.navigationController pushViewController:pageVC];
       }`

либо еще вариант вместо UIPageViewController можно использовать **UICollectionViewController** где каждая UICollectionViewCell и будет представлять из себя note editor. Этот метод проще, но может быть не так функционален, как через UIPageViewController

и самый просто способ:

пусть MYNoteEditorVC -  котроллер/эдитор для заметки

в нем

```
@property (nonatomic, string) NSArray *notes; // все заметки
```

добавляем метод

```
 - (void)reloadDataForNote:(MyNote *)note
```

который будет перегружать содержимое контроллера под новую заметку

дальше когда выбираем следующую или предыдущую заметку примо внутри этого контроллера

```
 - (IBAction)nextNotePressed
 {
if (self.currentNoteIndex + 1 < self.notes.count) {
MYNote *nextNote = self.notes[self.currentNoteIndex + 1];
self.currentNoteIndex++;
[self reloadDataForNote:nextNote];
}
}
```